# GRAPH Queries in Jena TDB: CLI works / Code fails

Tags: sparql, jena

I have created a TDB data set and loaded data into it. I want to execute the following query:

```
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
SELECT ?s WHERE  { GRAPH ?g { ?s skos:broader ?o }} LIMIT 100
```

In the command line, this query runs and returns the desired result using:

```
tdbquery --loc=<path_to_dataset> --file <path_to_query_file>
```

However, I am having trouble executing the very same query in Java code:

```
String pathToRepo = "<path_to_dataset>";

// open the dataset
dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(pathToRepo);

model = dataset.getDefaultModel();

String queryString = "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>\n"
                      + "SELECT ?s WHERE  { GRAPH ?g { ?s skos:broader ?o } } LIMIT 100";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
while (results.hasNext()) {
    QuerySolution result = results.next();
    System.out.println(result.get("s").toString());
}
qe.close();
```

The Java code runs but will not return any results.
Why is this the case? What do I have to change?

The data I use is public you can find it here: http://webisa.webdatacommons.org/ (scroll down until you are at Data Dumps).

I am new to Jena TDB, so I hope the question is not too stupid and not too hard to answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why don't you run the query against the dataset with [this method](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/QueryExecutionFactory.html#create-org.apache.jena.query.Query-org.apache.jena.query.Dataset-)?

Comment: Thank you! You are absolutely right. Querying against the dataset directly delivers the desired result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [AKSW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/aksw) points out correctly, the desired result can be obtained by querying against the dataset rather than the default model, i.e.,

```
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, dataset);
```